# Get jquery index of element - only including certain types of element

Tags: jquery, indexing

I have some code like this:

```
<h2 id="a">Header</h2>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<h2 id="zzz">Header</h2>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<h2 id="123">Header</h2>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to be able to determine, with jQuery, the index of a given h2, excluding all other elements, so only relating to h2 elements.  So for example, if I got the index of the item with id="123" it would return 3, as it's the third h2 in the tree.

I've tried this:

```
$('#123').index('h2');
```

But it doesn't seem to work.  It still counts the other elements at the same level of the DOM structure in the count.

Comment: keep in mind that "123" is not a valid value for the ID attribute.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have to specify the collection of elements, then use `index(<element>)` to get the index of the given element. Note: The argument must be a jQuery or DOM object. Strings don't work.
Note that JavaScript indices are zero-based, so an index of `2` actually means the *third element*.

```
$("#123").parent().children('h2').index($('#123'))
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2dg2q/**

Comment: this is genius!!, you need an award, and i guess they should create a news way to do it

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6ksujand/  just my example illustrating how good this answer is